# use storyboard in code Behind in winrt

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, storyboard

I need some help to animate an object to Circular path. for this purpose i create some `Method` in `LoadEvent` But I have no idea to add `Storyboard` to this Code.
`Storyboard` should change the location of my `Object` in Circular path.
Circular path Calculated by `AngelToPointMethod`.
If I `SetTargetProperty` to `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` my control move to Direct path but i need to move angel by angel.

here my Code

```
 public class Test : Canvas
{
     private int StartAngle = 215;
    private Rectangle _myControl = new Rectangle();
    private double _angle;
    public double Angle
    {
        get { return _angle;}
        set {_angle = value;}
    }
    public Test()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;  
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // UpdatePosition(_myControl, StartAngle);
        AnimatePositionAtTheFrist(StartOuterAngle);
    }

     static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,
                                  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        (obj as CircularSliderControl).OnPropertyChanged(args);
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        UpdatePosition(_myControl, StartAngle);
    }

    private void AnimatePositionAtTheFrist( int startAngle)
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = duration;
        //var da = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        var da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        da.Duration = duration;
        da.From = 0;
        da.To = startAngle;
        SineEase easingFunction = new SineEase();
        easingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;
        da.EasingFunction = easingFunction;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "Angle"); // error: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Angle on specified object.
        sb.Children.Add(da);
        sb.Begin();
    }
    private void UpdatePosition(Rectangle _myControl, int StartAngle)
    {
        var startPoint = AngelToPoint(StartAngle);
        var tr = new CompositeTransform();
        tr.TranslateX = startPoint.X;
        tr.TranslateY = startPoint.Y ;
        _myControl.RenderTransform = tr;
    }

}
```

## Update

I updated my code As above but i faced to two new problem

1: how to handle `propertyChanged` of `Angle` property?

Does the implementation that I've done, right?

I need run `UpdatePosition` just when the change value of `Angle` not all Properties.

2: how to `SetTargetProperty` to `Angle` property?

Comment: Maybe as inspiration: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/03/The-Animated-Pie-Slice-in-Windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a KeyFrame defined as :

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PaneGrid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="Frame1" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="Frame2" KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You can use x:Name attribute to let you find the Frame in your cs .
And you can find the ref of your Storyboard by its x:Name:

```
var stoaryboard = RootGrid.Resources["MyStoryboard"] as Stoaryboard;
stoaryboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Thanks @JuniperPhoton but my problem As I said above is how to move `myControl` in Circle. i recently try to do this but I dont have enough knowledge to handle `propertyChanged` and `SetTargetProperty`.

Comment: Can you specify your case so that I can come up with a better solution?

Comment: According to above code i try make a custom control that have a rectangle.so i need when my control start loading this rectangle move in Circle by storyboard. i calculated circle path by `angleToPoint`. i updated my Question Please see above code. "Thanks" again @JuniperPhton